# Can we control GPS tracker device in android

Tags: android, gps

We can track gps from device and get latitude and longitude of device and find location of device 
But is there any possibility of tracking any gps device from android phone programically
Here is one application in iphone this functionality is possible iphone but is there any possibility in android

[Control gps tracker device from iphone](http://www.starburstsoftware.co.uk/GPSTracker/)

Comment: i want to controll gps tracker device TK102 as in given link is it possible?

Comment: I see, you want the location of any external GPS unit. The TK102 appears to be a simple cell phone that you program to send SMS messages to your own phone of any type (Android, iPhone, Symbian, etc). But unless a GPS is programmed to broadcast it's location to you already, no app (Android or iPhone) can forcibly retrieve this information.